# gdal_calc and then gdal2tiles - scale colour and interpret nodata correctly

Tags: gdal

I have a GeoTiff file with 4 layers (red, green, blue, NIR).
The image has been clipped to a polygonal area, all data are set to 0 outside that area. It has Float32 as data type.

I want to calculate NDVI from this file and I want the pixels outside that particular area to be transparent.

As of now, I make a GeoTiff with NDVI:

```
gdal_calc.py --calc="(B - A) / (B + A) * (A > 0)" --outfile=ndvi.tif \
             -A source.tif --A_band 1 -B source.tif --B_band 4 \
             --NoDataValue=0
```

Then I run `gdal_tiles.py` on `ndvi.tif` to display the image on top of Google Maps, but the resulting image is not properly clipped (it's just grey outside of the field's borders, while I expect it to be transparent).

`gdalwarp` has a `-dstalpha` option that does the trick of making the nodata areas transparent - does `gdal_calc` has something similar? If it doesn't, what is the easiest way around it?